# Error running angular 17 with SSR and cloud functions

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions, angular17

Angular 17 build is generating below files

[image]

Before angular 17 my output is in format of index.js file .

Then i am calling the cloud function

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");
const mainjsfile= require(__dirname+"/server/main");

exports.ngssr=onRequest(mainjsfile.app());
```

Does anyone have idea how to call the server/ package mjs files using cloud functions in angular 17 application ?

I am getting below error :

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/n****l/Desktop/program/ui/ssrproject/ui/dist/functions2/lib/server/server.mjs not supported.
> Instead change the require of /Users/n****l/Desktop/program/ui/ssrproject/ui/dist/functions2/lib/server/server.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> at Object. (/Users/n****l/Desktop/program/ui/ssrproject/ui/dist/functions2/lib/index.js:16:19) {
> code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
> }

Please help to solve this issue